# Trying to read strings separated by a '/' from a file

Tags: c

I'm trying to read some strings which look like this in a txt file:

```
0001/ESIZON/Antonio.martin@esizon.com/antmar01/admin
0002/DISTGEN/donato.lima@distgen.com/donlim04/prov
```

I've tried to use the `fscanf` function with the following syntax:

```
fscanf(f_proveedor, "%[^/]/%[^/]/%[^%]/%[^/]/%s\n",
       proveedor[i].ID, proveedor[i].empresa, proveedor[i].email,
       proveedor[i].password, proveedor[i].tipo);
```

but as I try to read those strings my program crashes and I get nothing at the terminal.

(EDIT)

This is what I did now and it's working so far:

```c
#include "perfil.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 200

void temp_to_struct(sProveedor *proveedor, char temp[200], int pos);

void vaciar_vector(char v[200]);

void consultar_perfil(){
    int cont_proveedores = 0, i;
    char temp[MAX];
    sProveedor *proveedor;
    FILE *f_proveedor;
    if((f_proveedor = fopen("AdminProv.txt","r")) == NULL){
        puts("No se ha podido abrir el archivo AdminProv.txt");
    }
    else{
        while(fgets(temp, MAX, f_proveedor) != NULL){
            cont_proveedores++;
        }
        rewind(f_proveedor);
        if((proveedor = (sProveedor*)malloc(cont_proveedores*sizeof(sProveedor))) == NULL){
            puts("No se ha podido reservar memoria para sProveedor\n");
        }
        else{
            for(i = 0; i < cont_proveedores; i++){
                vaciar_vector(temp);
                fgets(temp,MAX,f_proveedor);
                temp_to_struct(proveedor,temp,i);
                printf("ID: %s\nEmpresa: %s\nEmail: %s\nContrasenya: %s\nTipo: %s\n\n",proveedor[i].ID,proveedor[i].empresa,proveedor[i].email,
                       proveedor[i].password,proveedor[i].tipo);
            }
            puts("BUCLE: ");
            puts("");
            /*for(i = 0; i < cont_proveedores; i++){
                printf("ID: %s\nEmpresa: %s\nEmail: %s\nContrasenya: %s\nTipo: %s\n\n",proveedor[i].ID,proveedor[i].empresa,proveedor[i].email,
                                                                                       proveedor[i].password,proveedor[i].tipo);
            }*/
        }
    }
}

void vaciar_vector(char v[200]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(v); i++){
        v[i] = '\0';
    }
}

void temp_to_struct(sProveedor *proveedor, char temp[200], int pos) {
    char *token[5];
    int i;
    token[0] = strtok(temp,"/");

    for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        token[i] = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }

    /*puts("TOKENS EN FUNCION: ");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Token %i: %s\n",i,token[i]);
    }*/

    proveedor[pos].ID = token[0];
    proveedor[pos].empresa = token[1];
    proveedor[pos].email = token[2];
    proveedor[pos].password = token[3];
    proveedor[pos].tipo = token[4];

    /*printf("PORFAVOR\nID: %s\nEmpresa: %s\nEmail: %s\nContrasenya: %s\nTipo: %s\n\n\n",proveedor[pos].ID,proveedor[pos].empresa,proveedor[pos].email,
           proveedor[pos].password,proveedor[pos].tipo);*/
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef ESIZONPROVEEDOR_PERFIL_H
#define ESIZONPROVEEDOR_PERFIL_H

typedef struct{
    char *ID;
    char *empresa;
    char *email;
    char *password;
    char *tipo;
}sProveedor;

void consultar_perfil();

#endif
```

Comment: All the `stuff[MAX]` should probably be just `stuff`. Please enable compiler warnings to catch such errors.

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong in all of the code that you are not showing. How are those variables created?

Comment: A few observations a) remove the final `\n` from the `fscanf` format string, and add a space in front of the first `%[^/]`. b) The input has 9 fields but you only read 5. c) check the return value from `fscanf` to ensure it read what it is supposed to read.

Comment: Re the added code: please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). The loop should be controlled by `fgets` like `while(fgets(temp,MAX,f_proveedor) != NULL)` and note I changed `200` to `MAX` too.

Comment: ... and note that the `fgets` loop leaves you at the end of file, so there is nothing for `fscanf` to read. **Always** check the return value from `scanf` function family.

Comment: That consistent use of `printf("Email: %s\n",temp_ID[MAX]);` means you have to go back to your class notes. And yeah, enable more compiler warnings.

Comment: @usr2564301 i'm just doing that to check if it's working i'll remove them later

Comment: He means the bad syntax: `temp_ID[MAX]` as mentioned earlier.

Comment: But it cannot work. The argument of `printf` (and your similar mistake in `fscanf`) is not `char x[SIZE]`.

Comment: was the added line `rewind(f_proveedor);` present in your actual code? If not, the edit is confusing.

Comment: @WeatherVane no, i noticed i needed to write it as i have to start to read the file again

Comment: You mean **I** [noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570339/trying-to-read-strings-separated-by-a-from-a-file?noredirect=1#comment107159202_60570339) you need to write it? Please note that adding corrections to the posted code is unhelpful to readers. Add them to your own version!

Comment: Read line with `fgets()` then split the fields with `strtok()`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm very sorry but this is the first post i make and i'm not used to this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Post the declaration of `sProveedor`

Comment: My initial reaction would be to read the entire file into memory and use strtok or something similar to handle this.  For HUGE gigabyte+ files, this won't work, but in general, it would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is you do not count the number of lines correctly:

`while (fgets(temp, MAX, f_proveedor) == NULL) {` will most likely exit immediately with a `0` count or will loop forever if the file is empty. You should test if the return value of `fgets()` is **!=** `NULL`.

The number of lines is `0`, you try and allocate `0` bytes, which on your platform returns a non `NULL` pointer, then the loop stops immediately and does not print anything to the terminal and your program continues in the `main` function, crashing or just exiting.

Also note the the format string is subtly incorrect and the return value of `fscanf()` is not tested:

- you do not specify the maximum number of characters to store into the destination arrays for the `%[^/]` conversion specifiers. If `MAX` is 100, you should use `%99[^/]`
- you use `%s` for the last field: if it has embedded spaces, only the first word with be copied.
- you have a trailing `\n` in the format: this will let `fscanf()` accepts any number of white space characters after the word. You should just accept and ignore a single newline with `%*1[/n]`

Try this format: `"%99[^/]/99%[^/]/99%[^%]/99%[^/]/99%[^\n]%*1[\n]"` and also check the return value of `fscanf()`: it should be 5 for a correctly parsed line. Any other number should be reported as a format error.